# Get video duration when input a video file on android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, video

I have follow this for detect video duration when input video file

" [Get video duration when input a video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285056/get-video-duration-when-input-a-video-file) "

but it not working on android. in IPhone and desktop is ok. what is the problem? anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you checked that javascript is enabled on your phone?

Comment: Please, share your code. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.