# angular2 get video duration before upload

Tags: html, angular, file-upload

I want to get video duration before upload. How to do this in angular2?
 There is my input code:

`<input type="file" class="form-control" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" accept="video/*" #video (change)="getVideoInfor(video.value) "/>`

I find some comparable example using jquery, but I have no idea to use in angualr2. Is it possible just using angular2 without jquery to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29285597/7270500 using javascript.

By the way, getVideoInfor is referring to video.value. 
This can easily be accessed using $event.target.value, saving you the #video reference, unless needed in your component's code.

Comment: I just found it, and it's amazing! I get the video.duration value what I want, but I have to use the value in my component.ts. How to output value of video.duration from video.onloadedmetadata() to component. I try many ways but can't access it. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Add a property to your component class and assign it in video.onloadedmetada(). In your template read that value using {{  }} syntax. See [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html) for examples

Comment: You save my life, and it's so glad that you response me patiently:)

Answer (score 0):

sorry wanted to comment to answered post but stack wont let me.

@PaulHuang would it be possible to see how you have implemented the answer? I have been trying to modify the answer in to my angular 2 but getting some errors that I cant get past.

Comment: Here you are,

`getDuration(files) {
        var myVideos = [];
        window.URL = window.URL;
        myVideos.push(files[0]);
        var a = [];
        var video = document.createElement('video');

        video.preload = 'metadata';
        video.onloadedmetadata = function( videoDuration) {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)
            a.push(video.duration);
        };
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
        this.videoDuration = a;

    }`

but I don't think it's the best way. If you find another better, please share to meXD