# Get a video duration on select in input file field keep throwing (Cannot read property '0' of undefined\)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried this function to get the duration of a video from input field but it keep saying

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined\

for the `files[0]`

```
 <input type="file" required="" id="id_video"></p>
 <input type="number" required="" id="id_duration"></p>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload">
 <pre id="infos"></pre>

<script>
var myVideos = [];

    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    document.getElementById('id_video').onchange = setFileInfo;

    function setFileInfo() {
        var files = this.files;
        myVideos.push(files[0]);
        var video = document.createElement('video');
        video.preload = 'metadata';

        video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
            var duration = video.duration;
            myVideos[myVideos.length - 1].duration = duration;
            updateInfos();
        }
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    }
    function updateInfos() {

        var infos = document.getElementById('infos');
        infos.textContent = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < myVideos.length; i++) {

            console.log(myVideos[i].duration)
            infos.textContent += myVideos[i].name + " duration: " + myVideos[i].duration + '\n';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `id_raw_file` ? where is this?

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285056/get-video-duration-when-input-a-video-file

Comment: my apologies I update my code

Comment: i've seen that link before but its not working, I'll try to give it a go again

Comment: Probably my bad, but how did you come include so many errors while copy-pasting this code? What should I have done to make it clearer?

Comment: @Kaiido sry about that, i alraedy added the `infos` tag and remove the extra semicolon , in `video.src` but its saying "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at HTMLInputElement.setFileInfo"

Comment: I'm using Chrome

Comment: In my code `files` is the Filelist, in yours it is the File, hence `files[0]` is undefined in yours.

Comment: bare with me for a while, in createObjectURL(files[0]), what actually I have pass inside the createObjectURL(), the file directory?

Comment: No you are passing `undefined` because you did declare `var files = this.files[0]` (a File object) while mine was `var files = this.files`, a FileList object)

Comment: @Kaiido updated my code, its not throwing me the error anymore but anything inside `video.onloadedmetadata = function` is not being trigger, I'm apologies for the complication

Answer (score 0):

You don't need call the function "setFileInfo" immediately, you just make the bind, remove the (). As @Pedram ask where the id_raw_file? I presume the id name is "id_video" and you forgot the create a container to received the texts infos e.g: . I hope helped

Comment: yes my apologies, I change the id name alraedy its `id_video` not `id_raw_file`

Comment: and I added the container `infos` as well