# Check length of uploaded video

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, video

Users are going to be uploading video contents to my WordPress site.

How do I reject content if more than 1 minute or 60 seconds. They will be uploading via html or ajax form. Which is better to achieve this, JavaScript or php?

Comment: WELCOME TO SO! please show your code...

Comment: Both JavaScript and PHP. You can't ensure your validation is going to work client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get video duration, dimension and size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847752/how-to-get-video-duration-dimension-and-size-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the video duration like that:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
var duration = document.getElementById("duration");

vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    duration.innerHTML = vid.duration;
});
```

```html
<div id="duration"></div>
<video src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" width=300 height=200 id="video"></video>
```

Otherwise, to get the video duration when the user select the file in the  File Browser, you can check the already answered question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29285597/1738016

Comment: Thanks much. I appreciate this