# Angular 2 app - get the duration of a mp3 upload

Tags: javascript, angular, mp3, angular2-forms

I've been trying for a long time to get the audio time (seconds) of a mp3 file upload in my Angular 2 App.

I've tried some different approaches ([one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285056/get-video-duration-when-input-a-video-file/29285597#29285597)), but i haven't been able to get it to work yet.

I was hoping to do it the Angular way - without calling `document.querySelector(...)` or `window.URL` for the  `URL.createObjectURL()`.

If i try with `@ViewChild('file')` and a function on the field called with `(change)` and call it with $event and the ViewChild:

`<input #file type="file" class="form-control-file" (change)="setFileField($event, file)">`

None of them contains the duration data, but i am able to get the file data through the event:

```
let files: FileList = event.target.files;
let file: File = files[0];

// File data from the event
lastModified: 1526819830000
lastModifiedDate: Sun May 20 2018 14:37:10 GMT+0200 (CEST) {}
name: "Det lægende samspil mellem det ydre og det indre mørke_pt1 - med Anders Laugesen.mp3"
size: 18792325
type: "audio/mp3"
```

If i wait and try to loop through the FormGroup data on the `(ngSubmit)`, the data isn't there as well.

I've read about an event called `(loadedmetadata)` but i can't get it to function in my app.

What should i do to get the duration of this file upload in an Angular 2 app, if i want to do it the Angular way?

Comment: Why the downvote? Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution i found was to combine angulars `(change)` and `(canplaythrough)`.

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" (change)="setFileField($event)">
<audio #dom_audio (canplaythrough)="setDuration($event)" id="audio"></audio>
```

The setFile gets the file from the files list, creates the object url and sets it in on the audio html tag:

```
setFile(event) {
  let files: FileList = event.target.files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    this.file = files[0];
  }
  if(this.file.name.match(/\.(avi|mp3|mp4|mpeg|ogg)$/i)){
    let obUrl = URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
    this.dom_audio.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', obUrl);
  }
}
```

Then, when the audio file can be played through - the `.duration` property is ready to be saved:

```
setDuration(load_event): void {
  this.duration = Math.round(load_event.currentTarget.duration);
}
```

And then i pass `this.duration` to the post params on `ngSubmit` and saves it in the database.

> **Note:** Remember to validate the presence of duration. You don't want the user to save the file without this attribute.

I hope it can help somebody.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me

Comment: Is there a good way to achieve the same behavior  for multiple selected audio files