# URL from File object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, blob, video-upload

Although, I have served quite some years in webdevelopment, I have to admit that I don't really know how (big) file uploads actually work. So I hope this question makes sense after all.

In my app I am uploading large video files to an S3 bucket. The uploading works like a charm but since we need to not only store the file but also **information about the file** in a database (eg. video duration), I was looking around how to accomplish this. I am using React, but I basically have an `onChange` handler on the `<input />` tag to get the **file object**

```js
<input type="file" onChange={() => handleChange()} />
```

In the `handleChange()` function, I assign the file object to a **state variable**

```
const handleChange = ( e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> ) {
  
  // TS checks and then assigning the file to a state variable
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length === 1) {
      setFile(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

After that I have some other handlers which handle the upload to S3 but this is all working. What I am interested in is how I can access information about the file which is going to be uploaded. Especially, I have noticed that **it takes some time BEFORE** the actual upload starts and I see activity in the network tab of the browser. So, **where is the file uploaded to?** Is that the browser cache?

After trying to find some more infos about what is happening I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285056/get-video-duration-when-input-a-video-file/29285597) on how to extract the video duration from the file, pre-upload. After extending `handleChange` I was able to get the video duration and assigning it to a state variable

```
const handleChange = ( e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> ) {
  
  // I have added !file since I don't want to create a feedback loop here
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length === 1 && !file) {
      setFile(event.target.files[0]);
      
      const vid = document.createElement("video");
      const fUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      vid.src = fUrl;
      vid.ondurationchange = () => {
        setDuration(vid.duration);
      };
  }
}
```

This works well. What I have realised when I do this I get to see a lot more activity in the **network tab** of my browser.
[image]

I assume that these entries are the blob ID of the `object URL` (here is where I really don't know what I am talking about). Looking at the requests in more detail I can see a **response header** with `Content Range` and I thought this would be perfect to show the "file preparation" process to the user BEFORE the actual upload begins.
[image]

How can I get access to this info? What exactly is happening here?

Thanks! Any help appreciated!

Comment: If the integrity of the data is important to you, then you might want to handle this on the server after uploading so that you can validate it. Any user can modify the JavaScript of your application in their browser and send false data to your endpoint(s).

Comment: +1 on what @jsejcksn said. Unless it's metadata that you're intending to send, trusting the client to not spoof this data is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response! Unfortunately, I do not really understand. What is the problem exactly? Is it the `const vid = document.createElement('video')` part?

Comment: ***where is the file uploaded to?*** in some buffer. File is basically some payload to HTTP, HTTP is payload to TCP and TCP packets are mostly written to a network buffer (in your local machine) before sending it to the network.

Comment: Thanks @kiner_shah! I thought that this would be the case. If I’d do `vid.preload = 'metadata'`, would that help regarding security?

Comment: @FlorianRagossnig `.. && !file` where is this variable declared?

Comment: BTW your question is unclear. What is it you are trying to do? Can you provide a exact summary of the requirement for the same?

Comment: Well, like I've stated in my question: I use **React** and thus the state variable **file** is set inside `handleChange` via `seFile(event.target.files[0])`. Regarding your further comment: I think I did state clearly what I am trying to do - I upload (large) video files to an S3 bucket and want to get **file meta information** BEFORE the actual upload starts. In my example I can already get the video duration but I have noticed that there is also a **Content Range** header which includes the bytes which are locally uploaded.